# AngularJS - How to trigger directive on bindHtml update?

Tags: svg, angularjs, jquery-svg

I have an example of the problem I am facing here: http://jsfiddle.net/Siyfion/JxLhX/

Essentially, I want to use jQuerySVG to attach some functionality to the SVG document (onClick, etc.) whenever the user clicks on a document from the list.

I know that DOM manipulation shouldn't be done in a controller function, so I've tried to create a directive to allow me to hook-in to the binding updates, but it doesn't fire when I'd expect it too (only once on page load atm).

The `<div>` tag that contains the binding to the SVG has the `id='drawContainer'` and is also where I have attached the directive:

```html
<div ng-app="module" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="SheetsCtrl">
    <div class="span3 well">
      <input type="text" ng-model="query" />
      <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header" ng-bind-template="Available Labels ({{getLabelCount()}})">Available Labels</li>
        <div id="sheetList">
          <li ng-repeat="label in labels | filter:query">
            <span>
              <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" ng-click="removeLabel(label)">
                <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
              </button>
              <a href="#" ng-click="getSVG(label)">{{label.Name}}</a>
            </span>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="span9" id="drawContainer" bind-to-svg ng-bind-html-unsafe="selectedLabelDesign"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

​
However I'm not sure that this is the correct way of doing things, here is the directive with a place-holder for the jQuerySVG code

```js
angular.module('module', []).directive('bindToSvg', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var svgDoc = element.children[0];
            alert('SVG Changed! (Or not, as the case may be)');
            // Attach jQuerySVG to svgDoc and register events.
        }
    };
});

function SheetsCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.selectedLabelDesign = null;

    $scope.labels[0] = {
        SVG: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" /></svg>',
        Name: 'Circle'
    };

    $scope.labels[1] = {
        SVG: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>',
        Name: 'Rectangle'
    };

    $scope.getLabelCount = function() {
        return $scope.labels.length;
    };

    $scope.getSVG = function(label) {
        var index = $scope.labels.indexOf(label);
        $scope.selectedLabelDesign = $scope.labels[index].SVG;
    };

    $scope.removeLabel = function(label) {
        var index = $scope.labels.indexOf(label);
        $scope.labels.splice(index, 1);
    };
}​
```

If anyone could give me any pointers in the right direction, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want it to do when it changes, but you could simply use a $watch to fire whatever it is you need to do.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedLabelDesign', function(value) {
    alert('SVG changed to: ' + value);
});
```

This watch could be set up either in your controller or your directive. Your call.

Comment: That doesn't really help with what I'm trying to achieve; that will fire as soon as I assign a new value to `selectedLabelDesign`. But I can't attach `onClick` handlers to it until it is in the DOM. So I need a way of being notified as and when the DOM is updated with the new SVG. Unless I'm missing something entirely!?

Comment: I guess it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. You want to bind a click event to the SVG after you swap it?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.